# Reinstall GRUB, which device to use?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

Earlier today my computer's boot drive had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed quite happily on it.

I could choose whether to boot Ubuntu or Windows via GRUB. I was also able to launch Ubuntu as a virtual machine inside VMWare Workstation.

Stupidly tonight, I ran the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from inside Ubuntu while it was being ran as a virtual machine in Windows.

This did something very strange. I'm not sure what, but when it was attempting to update GRUB, it completely crashed.

I restarted Windows, and that sent me to a weird looking GRUB screen; the normal grub screen but with `@` signs forming borders around the menu. Choosing Windows or Ubuntu resulted in a `Error: Command not found, press any key to continue` error. Pressing any key just brought me back to the main GRUB menu.

Everything's backed up, and I can see my boot drive using my Macrium live cd.

It has the following partitions:

```
1 - System Reserved = 100MB = This is something to do with Windows, but what? The UEFI bios?
2 - Boot (C:) = 83GB = This is where Windows 10 is installed
4 - (None) = 19.99GB = This where Ubuntu is installed
5 - (None) = 7.94GB = No idea what this is. 8 gb? Completely filled as well. What is this partition?
3 - (H:) = 450MB = No idea what this is.
```

So what do I run to restore grub to this drive? I gather I need to boot my bootable Ubuntu pendrive and run `grub-install /dev/xxxxx` however, I'm not sure what to replace `xxxxx` with.

I scanned my drives with an ubuntu application called 'boot repair' and this is what it gave me.

```
"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        42F031C2F031BCCB                       ntfs       Current
/dev/sdb1        9834F5D734F5B7F8                       ntfs       Archive
/dev/sdc1        7A900F02900EC51B                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sdc2        62BA1027BA0FF5F7                       ntfs       Boot
/dev/sdc3        8C009F66009F55D4                       ntfs       
/dev/sdc5        7d735d0f-0066-414d-88ad-2c49d8b7bbba   ext4       
/dev/sdc6        e2a27db6-9029-4cf6-903b-5403f64dc38d   swap       
/dev/sdd1        02FE-C63F                              vfat       UUI
/dev/sr0         2016-03-02-11-04-09-00                 udf        RESCUE
```

I think I need to run `grub-install /dev/sdc2` as "Boot" is what I called my boot drive, but I'm really not sure, and I don't want to damage anything, so I'd like confirmation. If someone could fill me in on what my mystery partitions (labelled `System Reserved`, `None` and `H` in my first table) are I would also be grateful.

Basically, what this boils down to is what path do I give `grub-install` inorder to reinstall grub, if that's even the way to fix my boot problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is which `sdX` you should use but not which `sdcY`. If `sda` and `sdb` are "data drives", then it would be `sdc`. The device specified is where grub will put its boot code / core image on, which should usually be the MBR and the post-MBR gap between that and the first partition of the boot disk.

The bigger concern is where the grub modules and so will be installed to. This is specified with the option `--boot-directory`, and its default is `/boot`. In your case, I don't see that you have a separate partition, so you need to get `sdc5` mounted in the live environment (e.g. on `/mnt`). Then you would either run:

```
grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/boot /dev/sdc
```

OR, if you can manage to chroot into `/mnt`:

```
grub-install --boot-directory /boot /dev/sdc
```

where `--boot-directory /boot` can be omitted since it's implied.

You may also want to explicitly specified `--target i386-pc` for `grub-install`, in case your system has UEFI instead of BIOS and your live environment is booted in UEFI mode somehow, instead of legacy mode like the system(s) on your boot disk (since it has no EFI System Partition, which technically should always be FAT12/16/32).

You probably need to run `update-grub` after `grub-install` to make sure `grub.cfg` is proper. Unlike `grub-install`, `update-grub` has to be run in a chroot AFAIK.

---

> 1 - System Reserved = 100MB = This is something to do with Windows,
>   but what? The UEFI bios?

System Reserved is like a `/boot` partition in Linux. It has a copy of Windows boot files (Windows Boot Manager, BCD Store...). Usually it also has a Windows Recovery Environment. It's separated mainly for BitLocker-encrypted system volume (`C:`) and Windows multi-boot.

> 5 - (None) = 7.94GB = No idea what this is. 8 gb? Completely filled as
>   well. What is this partition?

Apparently the `swap` partition.

> 3 - (H:) = 450MB = No idea what this is.

Probably some obsoleted OEM recovery partition. I bet it is originally larger and consists of a full-system recovery image, but has been removed and the partition was shrunk since you upgraded to Windows 10 or so (AFAIR Disk Cleanup also has an option to made that done).

Comment: Thanks very much, grub is now working and I can select and boot both of my operating systems. I think I'll look into deleting that old OEM recovery partition, thankyou